# Wordpress + SQL + Polylang function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to make table from `custom_post_type` named `company`. I have there company name, desc and meta tags for each record. This website is multilanguage, but i don't want to make double posts for each company so i've made extra fields `acf` for other lang etc.

When I'm on English version of page, everything is working great. The problems is on Polish version.

Here is a sql of getting all post by custom meta_key.

```
$all_posts = $wpdb->get_results( "
SELECT *, meta_value as meta_value_pl 
FROM $posts 
LEFT JOIN $postmeta 
ON ( $posts.ID = $postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE post_type = 'company' AND post_status = 'publish' AND $postmeta.meta_key = '$name' 
ORDER BY meta_value DESC 
LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

I want to make a virtual column of translation the meta_value and order by it. But i can't translate the meta_value by pll_() function because i can't place it there.

Ex:

```
$all_posts = $wpdb->get_results( "
SELECT *, pll__(meta_value) as meta_value_pl 
FROM $posts 
LEFT JOIN $postmeta 
ON ( $posts.ID = $postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE post_type = 'company' AND post_status = 'publish' AND $postmeta.meta_key = '$name' $where_search 
ORDER BY meta_value DESC 
LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

But i get this text 'pll__(meta_value)' in column, not the translation.

I don't know I'm explaining it very clear, but maybe someone will understand that :)

Comment: pick a server type with the tags.

Comment: i've picked a mysql server already :)

Comment: You are new. Just for your info, `sql-server` mean MSFT sql-server to everyone here. Oh, and welcome.

Comment: oh, your're right :) thanks!

Comment: what does this mean in the second block: `= '$name' $where_search`

Comment: How would whatever $where_search in there do ↑ anything ↑ but ↑choke it ↑

Comment: second bug. $where_search - should not be there this variable.